# explode json array in schema rdd

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a json like :

```
{"name":"Yin", "address":[{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"},{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}]} 
{"name":"Michael", "address":[{"city":null, "state":"California"},{"city":null, "state":"California"}]}
```

here address is an array and if i use `sqlContext.jsonfile` i get the data in schema rdd as follows :

```
[Yin , [(Columbus , Ohio) , (Columbus , Ohio)] 
[Micheal , [(null, California) , (null, California)]
```

I want to explode the array present and want the data in the following format in schema rdd :

```
[Yin, Columbus, Ohio] 
[Yin, Columbus, Ohio] 
[Micheal, null, California] 
[Micheal, null, California]
```

I am using spark SQL

Answer (score 4):

The typical suggestion is drop out of sql for this, but if you want to stay in SQL, here is an answer I got from asking this on the mailing list (nabble isn't showing the response for some reason):

**From Michael Armbrust**

You can do want with lateral view explode (using `HiveContext`), but what seems to be missing is that jsonRDD converts json objects into structs (fixed keys with a fixed order) and fields in a struct are accessed using a `.`

```
val myJson = sqlContext.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize("""{"foo":[{"bar":1},{"baz":2}]}""" :: Nil))
myJson.registerTempTable("JsonTest")​
val result = sql("SELECT f.bar FROM JsonTest LATERAL VIEW explode(foo) a AS f").collect()

myJson: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [foo: array<struct<bar:bigint,baz:bigint>>]
result: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1], [null])
```

In Spark 1.3 you can also hint to jsonRDD that you'd like the json objects converted into Maps (non-uniform keys) instead of structs, by manually specifying the schema of your JSON.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema =
  StructType(
    StructField("foo", ArrayType(MapType(StringType, IntegerType))) :: Nil)
​
sqlContext.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize("""{"foo":[{"bar":1},{"baz":2}]}""" :: Nil), schema).registerTempTable("jsonTest")
​
val withSql = sql("SELECT a FROM jsonTest LATERAL VIEW explode(foo) a AS a WHERE a['bar'] IS NOT NULL").collect()
​
val withSpark = sql("SELECT a FROM jsonTest LATERAL VIEW explode(foo) a AS a").rdd.filter  {
  case Row(a: Map[String, Int]) if a.contains("bar") => true
  case _: Row => false
}.collect()
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(foo,ArrayType(MapType(StringType,IntegerType,true),true),true))
withSql: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([Map(bar -> 1)])
withSpark: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([Map(bar -> 1)])
```

Comment: hey Justin, i tried your solution it gave me following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.36] failure: ``UNION'' expected but identifier VIEW found

SELECT f.bar FROM JsonTest LATERAL VIEW explode(foo) a AS f
                                   ^

Comment: P.S., i am using spark version 1.2, and you have used DataFrame which was introduced in spark 1.3

Comment: You need to be using HiveContext to use LATERAL VIEW